# Validation using Jquery of only checked rows of a multi row HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Given the following HTML table which is part of a form on a PHP page, what is the best practice for validating user input?

If a user checks a checkbox for a row (or multiple rows), what is the best way to ensure the StartDate and EndDate input fields have data using client side scripting.

I would like to use jquery but I am very new to jquery.  Would the jquery validation plugin make the most sense?

```
<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='Product[916109]' name='Product[916109]' value='916109' class='select'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='ProductName[916109]' name='ProductName[916109]' value='ESY792'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='StartDate[916109]' name='StartDate[916109]' class='startDatePicker'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='EndDate[916109]' name='EndDate[916109]' class='endDatePicker'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='Product[916110]' name='Product[916110]' value='916110' class='select'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='ProductName[916110]' name='ProductName[916110]' value='ESY793'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='StartDate[916110]' name='StartDate[916110]' class='startDatePicker'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='EndDate[916110]' name='EndDate[916110]' class='endDatePicker'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='Product[916111]' name='Product[916111]' value='916111' class='select'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='ProductName[916111]' name='ProductName[916111]' value='ESY794'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='StartDate[916111]' name='StartDate[916111]' class='startDatePicker'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='EndDate[916111]' name='EndDate[916111]' class='endDatePicker'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' id='Product[916112]' name='Product[916112]' value='916112' class='select'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='ProductName[916112]' name='ProductName[916112]' value='ESY795'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='StartDate[916112]' name='StartDate[916112]' class='startDatePicker'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' id='EndDate[916112]' name='EndDate[916112]' class='endDatePicker'>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='submit' id='btnSubmit' name='btnSubmit' value='Submit'>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: refer this to write runnable scippet in SO - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/  or use JSFiddle and share your fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for the use case you've described:

```
var theForm = $('form'),
  rows = theForm.find('tr');

theForm.on('submit', function(evt) {
  rows.each(function(i, row) {
    var valid = row.find( '.select' ).is( ':checked' )
             && ( row.find('.startDatePicker').val() && row.find('.endDatePicker').val() ) 

    if ( !valid ) return evt.preventDefault();
  } );
} );
```

No sense loading the validation plugin if that's all you need it for, but if you're likely to use it elsewhere then go for it.